# Name for half life where X axis is not time

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-function, exponential-distribution

In exponential decay (such as radioactive decay), there is a concept of "half life" $t_{1/2}$. It indicates a decay with "time".   But if the x-axis is not "time" (such as for an exponential probability distribution), but works exactly same as a half life; is there any name for the analogous concept where there is such a $\Delta (X)$ interval that makes $f(x)$ half each time?

Bonus question: is it closely related to $1/\lambda$? is there a name for $1/\lambda$?

Comment: Thank you for your bonus question.

Comment: Can anybody pls manage Greek letter formatting??

Comment: Input: $\$ \textrm{\delta}  \$$ $\Rightarrow$ Output: $\delta$

Comment: thank u editing soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is called the "decay constant."